# how to install in R CvM2SL2Test package (Cramer-von Mises Two Sample Test)

Tags: r

I am trying to install the following package CvM2SL2Test in R, but i do not manage to do it. I have tried from CRAN, but it seems that it is not available anymore. In the end, i have tried locally (downloading the package from http://ftp.naist.jp/pub/CRAN/src/contrib/Archive/CvM2SL2Test/) but i am obtaining the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/David/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'CvM2SL2Test' ...
** package 'CvM2SL2Test' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: comando ejecutado 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="CvM2SL2Test.dll" OBJECTS="CvM2SL2Test.o XCVM.o XCVMTailProb.o XCVMTailProb_EQ.o XCVMTailProb_NE1.o XCVMTailProb_NE2.o XCvMTest.o XFreqFunct.o"' tiene estatus 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'CvM2SL2Test'
* removing 'C:/Users/David/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/CvM2SL2Test'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\David\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "C:/Users/David/Downloads/CvM2SL2Test_2.0-1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/David/Downloads/CvM2SL2Test_2.0-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Given that i am using windows 10, i have extracted the folder, and used the extention .zip. Then i have been able to obtain the following result:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/David/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘CvM2SL2Test’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

However, when using like library(‘CvM2SL2Test’), I see the following:

```
library('CvM2SL2Test')
Error in library("CvM2SL2Test") : 
  ‘CvM2SL2Test’ is not a valid installed package
```

I do not know how to install propery this package in windows 10 in order to use it properly, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a problem running the `make` command.  This probably indicates that you don't have the R Tools collection (see https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed, or it is not installed properly.